# can i apply as Asylum seeker in a country that is different from the country that i have got the residence permit from?

Tags: schengen, asylum

More detailed version of the question
I am from Syria :(. I traveled to a Schengen country legally (to Spain) as a student, after one month that country, gave me a temporary residence permit (long term: 1 year). Note: i have not applied for Asylum in Spain.

i know i can travel to any other Schengen country using that resident permit.

My question is: can i apply as Asylum seeker in a country that is different from the country that i have got the residence permit from, e.g. Norway?

Comment: On what grounds would you be seeking asylum? IIRC Spain is a safe country, and doesn't persecute Syrians in any way.

Comment: @littleadv presumably the grounds are related to the fact that he'll have to leave Spain after one year.

Comment: i would say he can object deportation from where he is now, but I don't think he can say he's in mortal danger in Spain.